# IntelliJ - "ADB not responding"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb

I work with:
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6
on Windows 7

When i try to Run new project (simple auto created Hello World) InteliJ display window with comunicate "Waiting for ADB" and then "ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb.exe" process manually and click 'Restart'".
So 'Wait more' effects the same communicates, same as killing ADB and 'Restart'.
I tryed to "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" in console but it dont fixed my problem.

My device is connected to adb.

Comment: Probably restart the machine or wait for some time like 5 mins for adb to respond.

Comment: @johntheripp3r That solution don't works. :(

Comment: did android sdk work fine?

Comment: @johntheripp3r Yea, I gues. Hello Wolrd is compiled succesfull. ADB see mobile device connected to pc. Just InteliJ dont see ADB.

Comment: If you want to continue with IntelliJ - try re-installing. Otherwise android sdk is always at your disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work with ADT?

I don't have much experience with InteliJ, but in ADT you have to specify a path to Android SDK so it can find and run adb. If there are no such settings, try adding path to android sdk tools ( the folder where adb.exe is located ) to your system PATH.